# Error on Kotlin Muliplatform Ktor Integration

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I've followed the guide from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-upgrade-app.html#ktor it throws the following error when run `kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.0"`.

```
Execution failed for task ':shared:compileDebugKotlinAndroid'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared:kotlinCompilerPluginClasspathAndroidDebug'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization-compiler-plugin-embeddable:1.8.21.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-serialization-compiler-plugin-embeddable/1.8.21/kotlin-serialization-compiler-plugin-embeddable-1.8.21.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-serialization-compiler-plugin-embeddable/1.8.21/kotlin-serialization-compiler-plugin-embeddable-1.8.21.pom
     Required by:
         project :shared

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem begin with Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1 create a KMM app with dependency version 1.8.21 that's why serializing version 1.9.0 was not able to resolve

Change following

```
kotlin("android").version("1.8.21").apply(false)
kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.8.21").apply(false)
```

to

```
kotlin("android").version("1.9.0").apply(false)
kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.9.0").apply(false)
```

And if u face jetpack compose a version mismatch with 1.9.0 change compose version according to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#kts